# data-transition working for <a> tag , but not for button onClick

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I applied page transition in my html code. It's working fine under  tag but not working under button click. My browser: Firefox 15.0.1

Here is My code: Working fine:

```
 Don't have a login? <a href="#signup" data-transition="slide" >Sign Up</a>
```

Not Working:

```
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Login" data-role="button" onClick="location.href='#details';" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" />
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `type="submit"` into `type="button"` as below:

```
<input id="Submit1" type="button" value="Login" data-role="button" onclick="location.href='#details';" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" >
```

Comment: I have removed your blog link from this post, as well. Again, your blog post had *absolutely nothing* to do with the question asked (your post was about ASP.NET; this is not). And again, you should not be linking to your blog in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this particular framework myself, but from the [site](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html):

> The jQuery Mobile framework includes a set of six CSS-based transition effects that can be applied to any page link or form submission with Ajax navigation [..]

Have you tried applying the attribute to your form tag?

```
<form action=".." method=".." data-transition="slide">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Tried that way but not working... I Managed like this: <a href="#details"  data-role="button" data-transition="slide" >Login</a> .. Now it's working fine like a button..